# Masstransit not creating Error queue for Azure Function event subscriber

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-servicebus-topics

We followed this example (http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/azure-functions.html) to try to set up Azure Functions as Azure Service Bus event (topic) subscribers using MassTransit (for .Net CORE 2.1, Azure Functions 2.0).

When using Azure Webjobs this is as simple as using RabbitMQ, configure the publisher, let the subscriber configure and set up its queue, and have Masstransit automatically create one topic per event, redirect to queue and to "queue_error" after all retries have failed. You do not have to setup anything manually.

But with Azure Functions we seem to manually (through Service Bus Explorer or ARM templates) have to add the subscribers to the topic (which is created by the publisher on the first event it publishes) and the queues as well (though these don't even seem to be necessary, the events are handled directly by the consuming Azure Function topic subscribers.).

Maybe we are doing something wrong, I cannot see from the docs that MT will not, as it normally does, set up the subscriber andd creating queues when using Azure Functions. But it works, except for when the consumer throws an exception and after all setup retries have been executed. We simply do not get the event in the deadletter queue and the normally MT-generated error queue does not even get generated.

So how do we get MT to create the error queues, and MOVE the failed events there?

Our code:

```
    [FunctionName("OrderShippedConsumer")]
    public static Task OrderShippedConsumer(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("xyz.events.order/iordershipped", "ordershippedconsumer-queue", Connection = "AzureServiceBus")] Message message, 
        IBinder binder,
        ILogger logger,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken,
        ExecutionContext context)
    {
        var config = CreateConfig(context);

        var handler = Bus.Factory.CreateBrokeredMessageReceiver(binder, cfg =>
        {
            var serviceBusEndpoint = Parse.ConnectionString(config["AzureServiceBus"])["Endpoint"];
            cfg.CancellationToken = cancellationToken;
            cfg.SetLog(logger);
            cfg.InputAddress = new Uri($"{serviceBusEndpoint}{QueueName}");

            cfg.UseRetry(x => x.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)));
            cfg.Consumer(() => new OrderShippedConsumer(cfg.Log, config));
        });
        return handler.Handle(message);
    }
```

---

And the Consumer code:

```
    public OrderShippedConsumer(ILog log, IConfigurationRoot config)
    {
        this.config = config;
        this.log = log;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IOrderShipped> context)
    {
       // Handle the event
    }
}
```

Comment: For Azure Functions, there is no subscription that MT cat set up for you, that's what you do when you create the function. Also, the error handling is done by the Functions engine according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages. Functions have their own poison queues https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#trigger---poison-messages

Comment: Thanks, interesting articles! 
I was aware of the built-in retries of Azure Functions, but have not really seen this "in action" since the retries seem to be handled by MT, the retry policy configured in the consumer is the one being used: one single retry after 5 secs according to our code above. Nothing else. Plus, we don´t get a poison queue created either after all retries have failed. Do we need to do anything else than just throwing an exception from the Consume-method?

Comment: Alexey is right, functions have their own error handling, MT just let's you consume and publish/send other messages via the collectors.

Comment: Thank you. So basically we don't need to config retries through MT, instead just use the built-in retries and have the event moved to the poison queue when failed after (default) 5 retries?
Anyway, at the moment we don't get a poison queue at all, the messages just disappear after the MT-configured retry (one after 5 secs) . 
I suspect we may have to enable the Service Bus Topic Trigger Extension manually on the portal for this to work, as stated here: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/819#issuecomment-395104399 (getting an error in the portal when trying though)

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue. The message doesn't go to the dead letter queue, nor to the error/poisoned queue. Did you find a solution?